# segmentation fault when building Plutus-playground.server

Tags: plutus-playground, build

I'm following the instructions for installing the Plutus-playground found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/mmzut6/macos_plutus_playground_build_instructions/)

I discovered I must execute the following before step 10

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
```

I `cd` into plutus-apps/ and this then worked fine (note: in `zsh`):

```
[zsh]$ pwd
/Users/jwb/plutus/plutus-apps
[zsh]$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.client
```

But I got a "segmentation fault" with this:

```
[zsh]$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
```

Here is the output for clarity:

```
[zsh]$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
zsh: segmentation fault
```

I switched to `bash` after the error, but that too failed:

```
[bash]$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Is the plutus-apps repository corrupted? Why would the client build just fine but not the server?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try running `GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-build -A plutus-playground.server`.

Comment: Running macOS Big Sur and this answer solved it for me